# How can i merge Two script work into one, Like see this

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is two text-area and, the first one is used to Randomize Lines, and the second one is for Removing Empty Lines by each Submit button that Named as according to their work.

Okay but i want to merge these two different different work into one, means only from one textarea we can remove all empty lines and also with shuffle / Randomizing lines with only one button Named As **`Randomize & Remove empty Lines`**

How can i do that plz help me.

What i have tried that not working is: i merged both script into one like this:

```
$(function () {
    mkTool('random-lines', function (text) {
        text = text.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n');
        var lines = text.split('\n');

        function KnuthShuffle (array) {
            var currentIndex = array.length;
            var temporaryValue;
            var randomIndex;

            while (0 !== currentIndex) {
                randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
                currentIndex -= 1;
                temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
                array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
                array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
            }

            return array;
        }

        lines = KnuthShuffle(lines);
                var ret = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            var line = lines[i];
            if (/^[\s\t]*$/.test(line)) {
                continue;
            }
            ret += line + '\n';
        }
        

        return lines.join('\n');
        return ret;

    });
});
```

**My Whole Code is:**

```html
<div id="tool-implementation">
          
<div id="tool-random-lines">
  <div class="field">
    <textarea id="random-lines-text"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div id="action-error"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="submit" value="Randomize Lines!" id="random-lines-submit"> 
</div>

        </div>

--------------------

<div id="tool-implementation">
          
<div id="tool-empty-lines">
  <div class="field">
    <textarea id="empty-lines-text"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div id="action-error" style="display: none;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="submit" value="Remove Empty Lines!" id="empty-lines-submit"> <span id="copy-to-clipboard">
  </div>
</div>

        </div>
        
        <br>  <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
---------------
<style>
#tool-implementation .field textarea {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
}
</style>

<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bjm3vu7ps482fm4/tools.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
// Script for Randomize Lines
$(function () {
    mkTool('random-lines', function (text) {
        text = text.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n');
        var lines = text.split('\n');

        function KnuthShuffle (array) {
            var currentIndex = array.length;
            var temporaryValue;
            var randomIndex;

            while (0 !== currentIndex) {
                randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
                currentIndex -= 1;
                temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
                array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
                array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
            }

            return array;
        }

        lines = KnuthShuffle(lines);

        return lines.join('\n');
    });
});
</script>

<script>
// Script for Remove Empty Lines
$(function () {
    mkTool('empty-lines', function (text) {
        text = text.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n');
        var lines = text.split('\n');
        var ret = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            var line = lines[i];
            if (/^[\s\t]*$/.test(line)) {
                continue;
            }
            ret += line + '\n';
        }
        return ret;
    });
});

</script>
```

plz ignore the error from Dropbox JS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the modified code.

```
<div id="tool-implementation">

  <div id="tool-random-lines">
    <div class="field">
      <textarea id="random-lines-text"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <div id="action-error"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <input type="submit" value="Randomize Lines!" id="random-lines-submit">
    </div>

  </div>

  <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
  ---------------
  <style>
    #tool-implementation .field textarea {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 450px;
      height: 200px;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bjm3vu7ps482fm4/tools.js"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <script>
    // Script for Randomize Lines
    $(function () {
      mkTool('random-lines', function (text) {
        text = text.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n');
        var lines = text.split('\n');

        function KnuthShuffle(array) {
          var currentIndex = array.length;
          var temporaryValue;
          var randomIndex;

          while (0 !== currentIndex) {
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
          }

          return array;
        }

        lines = KnuthShuffle(lines);

        return lines.join('\n');
      });
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    // Script for Remove Empty Lines
    $(function () {
      mkTool('random-lines', function (text) {
        text = text.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n');
        var lines = text.split('\n');
        var ret = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
          var line = lines[i];
          if (/^[\s\t]*$/.test(line)) {
            continue;
          }
          ret += line + '\n';
        }
        return ret;
      });
    });

  </script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. See [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837).